# How to make a button to run GoLand in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, goland

I'm running GoLand by the `./goland.sh` command in the terminal

How do I make a button to start Gogland by pressing?

I use linux ubuntu

Comment: A button? What GUI library are you talking about?

Comment: He is talking about a launcher and Gogland is an IDE

Comment: I think it is much more clear after the edit. Could you unblock the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question 100% but I believe the answer is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the free JetBrains Toolbox:

https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/

Not only will create launchers but will keep everything up-to-date.

I really like it and I am sure you will.

Comment: I like it.
But he does not see my PhpStorm and Gogland. Suggests to reinstall

Comment: Yes but you won't lose any configuration (that is in your home directory).

Comment: Plus, you will be able to update automatically and easily